# Stored Procedure PL SQL If String Is blank

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I got a problem with Oracle Stored Procedure. The `if else` statement didnt check whether the string is blank or not. Or am I doing it wrong?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GET_ICECREAM
(
   flavour IN VARCHAR2,
   toppings IN VARCHAR2,
   cursorIC OUT sys_refcursor
)
AS

dynaQuery VARCHAR2(8000);

BEGIN

dynaQuery := 'SELECT price FROM tblIceCream';

IF flavour <> '' THEN

   dynaQuery := dynaQuery || ' WHERE flavour LIKE '''%''' '

ENDIF



OPEN cursorIC FOR dynaQuery;

END GET_ICECREAM;
```

DISCLAIMER: Above is not actual stored procedure. I'm using an example to understand concept of if else and native dynamic SQL in Oracle. So that its easier for you guys to understand ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hope this below snippet will help you to understand how to handle empty string and NULL values.

```
SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
  lv_var VARCHAR2(100):='';
BEGIN
  IF lv_var IS NULL THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('is null');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('av');
  END IF;
END;

------------------------------------OUTPUT--------------------------------------

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

is null

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
  lv_var VARCHAR2(100):='';
BEGIN
  IF lv_var = '' THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('is null');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('av');
  END IF;
END;

--------------------------------------output-----------------------------------
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

av

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 9):

In PL/SQL, a zero length string that is assigned to a `varchar2` variable is treated as a `NULL`.

In your case, if argument `flavour` is assigned a zero length string, the line below is actually comparing a `NULL` to *something*, which is always false.

```
IF flavour <> '' then
```

Fix that line according to your business logic to take care of null values for `flavour`, and you'll be fine. An example fix would be:

```
if flavour is not null then
```

Answer (score 5):

In Oracle, the empty string is equivalent to `NULL`.

So you want to do:

```
IF flavour IS NOT NULL THEN
```

However, a better solution is not to use dynamic SQL but to re-write the `WHERE` filter:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GET_ICECREAM
(
   flavour IN VARCHAR2,
   topping IN VARCHAR2,
   cursorIC OUT sys_refcursor
)
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN cursorIC FOR
  SELECT price
  FROM   tblIceCream
  WHERE  ( flavour IS NULL OR your_flavour_column LIKE '%' || flavour || '%' )
  AND    ( topping IS NULL or your_topping_column LIKE '%' || topping || '%' );
END GET_ICECREAM;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:

```
IF NVL(flavour, 'NULL') <> 'NULL'
```